# SSIS Script Component - How to modify the Output0Buffer

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I've a script component which accepts records from SQL Azure database table. The script then invokes a web service, which returns the number of failed and success records.

For all the records, I would like to add the Status field which has either "success" or "fail" and this gets output from script component.

I then log those output into a text file.

Problem:
I'm not been able to add status for each input records since the web service call only happens on post execute.

I tried this but still doesn't work:

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
         listOfData.Add(new ClockData 
         {
             TimeClockID=Row.TimeClockID,
             PersonID=Row.EmployeeCode,
             LocationCode=Row.ClockInServiceContextID,
             ClockInDateTime=Row.ClockInDateTime,
             ClockOutDateTime=Row.ClockOutDateTime

         });
 }

 public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
 {
     MessageBox.Show("Test CreateNewOutputRows");
     MessageBox.Show(listOfData.Count.ToString());
     foreach (var item in listOfData)
     {
         Output0Buffer.AddRow();
         Output0Buffer.EmployeeCode = item.PersonID;
         MessageBox.Show(item.PersonID);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Why can you not execute the web service call during the processinputrows? All the data has already gone down the pipeline once it's out of that method. You are accumulating data in your local variable but at this point it's like holding a picture of a car that just drove away-yes, that's what it looked like but it's not coming back

Comment: @flybyte: anything useful in my answer?

Answer (score 7):

Everything in a Transformation is done within Input0_ProcessInputRow
The solution would essentially be

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
         listOfData.Add(new ClockData 
         {
             TimeClockID=Row.TimeClockID,
             PersonID=Row.EmployeeCode,
             LocationCode=Row.ClockInServiceContextID,
             ClockInDateTime=Row.ClockInDateTime,
             ClockOutDateTime=Row.ClockOutDateTime
         });
         Output0Buffer.AddRow();
         Output0Buffer.EmployeeCode = item.PersonID;
         MessageBox.Show(item.PersonID);
}
```

You may be able to perform the output steps in PostExecute, CreateNewOutputRows is not run in Transformation, only in Destination scripts.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not very proficient in SSIS, but I think that you could try the following ideas:

- go to the script component and edit it,
- go to section Inputs and Outputs (3rd section),
- go to Output0 - Output columns,
- add a new column (give it a name and type, let's say Status - boolean).

Then you'd have the empty column to your output and you will need to populate it with some data for each of the input rows:

```
Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)
    Row.Status = IIf(String.IsNullOrEmpty(rowValues.GetValue(1).ToString()), 0, 1)
```

This will help you add a Status column to your output table. Hope this is what you wanted.